# Can std::this_thread::sleep_for() have spurious wakeups?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, sleep, thread-sleep

Note, this is not a question about `std::condition_variable::wait_for()`. I know that can wake spuriously.

My program’s behavior suggests the answer to this question is Yes, but the STL documentation is quite clear for the condition_variable case. At least at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), the correct answer for this_thread appears to be No.

Compiler is gcc 4.8.1, in case this is a defect.

Comment: How do you measure the time?

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds(50)` I was running a unit test with many timestamped messages and there was no corresponding gap. Indeed, this caused the test to fail.

Comment: I can't find any mention of spurious wakeups for `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` in the `C++11` standard. Only for `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: Did you link the thread library in?

Comment: Well `sleep_for` is implemented on top of `usleep`/`sleep`. I assume that a bug there is unlikely.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce, do you have an example code that fails?

Comment: Just a thought, are you using the `std::chrono::steady_clock`? The `C++11` standard says you *should* use a steady clock.

Comment: @Galik No, it says the *implementation* should use a steady clock. A `duration` has no clock associated with it.

Comment: @Galik Sometimes it's fine, but the code would not be very interesting. `LOG("stuff"); std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(50); LOG("More stuff")` where LOG is a macro that includes a timestamp in the output. I was at the terminal when this ran, and I could just tell without looking there was no 50 second sleep.

Comment: DID YOU LINK THE THREAD LIBRARY IN?  (What are your compiler command line options, all of them please)

Comment: You are not using `std::clock` to compute the timestamps, aren't you?

Comment: Able to reproduce on GCC 4.8.5. There is also a bug reported (and confirmed) against GCC 5.1.0 (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66803)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant sections of the C++ Standard (paragraphs [thread.thread.this]/7-9) do not mention anything about spurious wake-ups for `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, unlike e.g. for  `std::condition_variable::wait_for`.

> ```
> template <class Rep, class Period>
> void sleep_for(const chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time);
> ```
>
> 7 *Effects*: Blocks the calling thread for the relative timeout (30.2.4) specified by `rel_time`.
>
> 8 *Synchronization*: None.
>
> 9 *Throws*: Timeout-related exceptions (30.2.4).

This implies that the behavior you are observing is non-conforming.

Answer (score 4):

Able to reproduce on GCC 4.8.5.

There is also a bug reported (and confirmed) against GCC 5.1.0 ([gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66803](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66803))